# Can I request for junior freelancing job on freelancing beta

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

Recently, I came to know that we have https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/. And I was wondering, if I can post something like

> Looking for freelancing job as junior Android developer............
>   ..................... ................................
>   ................................................

I want to know if that is okay to post?

Thank you

Comment: Nice that you asked first though, so +1 from me, although, as per the close reason, you should ask such questions on the meta of the relevant site ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not okay.

For a description of what *is* on-topic for Freelancing, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: But I see **Selling services to different employers without a long-term contract with any of them** which should also be the other way if I get it

Comment: @Nabin That means __asking questions__  about selling services is okay. Selling services isn't.